# Small function and level of abstraction - clean code - refactor further

Tags: c#

In the book `Clean Code` from Robert C. Martin are given many recommendations. Two of them are

- to keep functions small and
- within a function to only have one level of abstraction.

I already cleaned the following method up a bit by extracting a few methods (`RemoveFontColor()`, `RemoveTextHighlight()`). But i am not sure if the few-liners (font-style, font-weight, etc.) should be extracted into a method as well. The advise from the author is to not mix different-levels of abstraction within a function because this could lead to other details creeping in. This would mean that even the two liners will be extracted into their own methods.

#### The partly refactored code example

```
private string Fix(FixPreferences preferences,string value)
{
    if (preferences.IsRemoveBold) {
        value = value.Replace("font-weight:bold", "font-weight:normal");
        value = value.Replace("font-weight: bold", "font-weight:normal");
    }
    if (preferences.IsRemoveItalics) {
        value = value.Replace("font-style:italic;", "font-style:normal;");
        value = value.Replace("font-style: italic;", "font-style:normal;");
    }    
    if (preferences.IsRemoveFontColor) {
        value = RemoveFontColor(value);
    }
    if (preferences.IsRemoveTextHighlight) {
        value = RemoveTextHighlight(value);
    }  
    if (preferences.IsRemoveStrikethrough){
       value = 
        value.Replace("text-decoration: line-through;", "text-decoration:none;");
       value = 
        value.Replace("text-decoration:line-through;", "text-decoration:none;");
    }
    if (preferences.IsRemoveUnderline)
    {           
      value = 
       value.Replace("text-decoration: underline;", "text-decoration:none;");
      value = 
       value.Replace("text-decoration:underline;", "text-decoration:none;");
    }
    return value;
}
```

### Update

I changed to extract even the few lines - but it still looks not pretty.

```
    private string Fix(ChangeLogFixOperationPreferences preferences,string value)
    {
        if (preferences.IsRemoveBold)
                value = RemoveBold(value);

        if (preferences.IsRemoveItalics)
                value = RemoveItalics(value);

        if (preferences.IsRemoveFontColor)
                value = RemoveFontColor(value);

        if (preferences.IsRemoveTextHighlight)
                value = RemoveTextHighlight(value);

        if (preferences.IsRemoveStrikethrough)
                value = RemoveStrikethrough(value);

        if (preferences.IsRemoveUnderline)
                value = RemoveUnderline(value);

        if (preferences.IsResetFontSize)
                value = ResetFontSize(value);

        return value;
    }
```

Is there a better way - for example to put the preferences and the methods into a dictionary and for each preference that is set to true the function from the dictionary is called within a loop?

#### My question

- How would you refactor the code above?
- Are there any ways to group the different `font-*` or `text-decoration:*` togehter in one function? Would that be wise since it violates the single responsibility pattern (SRI)?
- Update: Would you recommend calling a function from a dictionary

  - [store functions in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233536/c-sharp-store-functions-in-a-dictionary) or may be
  - [call method dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251951/call-a-method-dynamically-based-on-some-other-variable) or
  - from Jon Skeet [storing functions in a dictionary by using Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125717/how-to-store-functions-in-dictionary-with-uint-as-key-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, each condition and formatting will be moved to your own class. Let's create a common interface:

```
interface FormattingRemover
{
    bool Match(string value);
    string RemoveFormat(string value);
}
```

Now we can use it to abstract the formatting:

```
public class RemoveBold : FormattingRemover
{
    public bool Match(string value) {
        // your condition here
        return true;
    }

    public string RemoveFormat(string value) {
        return RemoveBold(value);
    }
}
```

In your class you'll need a list with all implementantions of FormattingRemover, iterate over it and when the value matches, you can remove its formatting.

```
private removers = AllRemovers();

private string Fix(ChangeLogFixOperationPreferences preferences,string value)
{
    foreach (var remover in removers)
    {
        if (remover.Match(value))
        {
            value = remover.RemoveFormat(value);
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

For now on, you just need to add new implementations to provide it with AllRemovers. A good idea is inject it with some DI container, like Ninject.

Comment: What would be in `private removers = AllRemovers();` ? Would it contain a List of all `preferences` (IsRemoveBold, IsRemoveUnderline, ...) which formating should be removed?

Comment: `AllRemovers()` is a method which populate and returns a List of all implementantions of `FormattingRemover`. The class `RemoveBold` is an example of how this should be done.